# Every linux distribution completely stop working and freezes on my ASUS N82jQ notebook after a while!

Tags: drivers, asus

I'm a windows guy that decided to move on Linux on my laptop. Unfortunately for my ASUS N82JQ (*Intel Core i7 720QM, 6G DDR3 RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GT 335M with 1GB DDR3 VRAM*) it's regular that CPU temps reach more than 90 centigrade degrees and it wont make any problem on windows 7.

But as I moved on Linux and tested latest version of every distribution like **Ubuntu**, **Mint(cinnamon,mate,KDE,XFCE)**, **Fedora(workstation)**, **Xubuntu** and even **OpenSUSE** I feel something wrong cause after a while and working on and doing nothing special (*web browsing with Firefox or editing google docs*), when CPU temps goes high everything stops working and desktop freezes (*turning off and on is not effective either and it freezes in a less time duration because CPU is still hot*).

**Is really Linux incompatible with my laptop or there is a solution to this issue?**

Comment: You need to install Nvidia drivers. But do not download them from Nvidia site. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Nvidia drivers. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt install nvidia-340 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

You will be able to switch graphics in Nvidia X Server Settings application (PRIME section).

I recommend to switch to Intel, if you are not playing games.

Comment: So it's all about Nvidia. I'm not playing games but 3D designs or photo editing is part of my work. I gonna test that. thanks

Comment: Without the driver both adapters work and consume power. That's the reason of overheating. You can use Nvidia if you like. But you need to log off and log on after switch.

Comment: well well :)
I did the exact command and the result was awesome... everything's run perfect after non stop working. thanks a lot. and the point that dear Pilot6 said not to dl the package from nvidia was completely effective for me.